# trouble putting variable into the variable

Tags: python, django, for-loop

I have many icons, with names icon1, icon2, icon3 and so on... which are coming from server

how can I make a forloop and set that icon`NUMBER` in a loop automatically?.

I tried this:

```
{% for i in "1234" %}
  {{icon}}{{forloop.counter}}
{% endfor %}
```

but this is not giving me what I want. why cannot I do something like this:

```
{{ icon{{forloop.counter}} }},
```

but this is giving me error, saying it cannot parse the expression

Comment: Can you show full code which includes loops over icons also? `{{icon}}{{forloop.counter}}` is the right way to do but what's you want?

Comment: @AamirAdnan, i dont have full code yet, i am testing this possibility, then i will loop over icons. if i get icon1, icon2 from this test code, then i will write the rest code for real loop. so my question is, how is it possible?

Comment: i have not downvoted you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for concatenation of your `icon` variable and for loop counter.

```
{% for i in "1234" %}
 {% with c=forloop.counter|stringformat:"s" %}
  {{icon|add:c}}
 {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is not really what i want. It is adding some value and not concatenating

Comment: @doniyor see my edit. If `icon` is also an integer, you will need to convert it to string as well using `with` .